# Comparing negative values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In 1 table I am comparing negative values but it is not giving required results.
In below table need to flag anyone has Mod_Value more than 10% of Metric_Value

```
Table Columns : Emp ID , Name , Mod_Name , Mod_Value , Metric_Value
```

So my code is:

```
Select Distinct Emp_ID , Name , Mod_Name , Mod_Value , Metric_Value
where  Mod_Value > (0.1*Metric_Value) from Mod_Table
```

and 1 Emp is getting flagged that as below

```
EmpId  name  Mod_Name  Mod_Value  Metric_Value
123    ABC   PQR       -110243    -6124550
```

where as 10% of -6124550 is -612455 can someone please tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is missing a `from` so it will not run.

Comment: `-3` is ***less than*** `-1`, not more than...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic arithmetic:  -110,243 is greater than -612,445 because it is "less" negative.

You seem to want `<` rather than `>` or to compare the absolute values:

```
where abs(Mod_Value) > 0.1 * abs(Metric_Value)
```

Comment: thank you so much it resolved the problem .